# How to disable template check with production mode? Angular 2

Tags: angular, templates, ionic2

I have component where I get template via function or variable.
For example:

```js
@Component({
   template: getTemplate('pathToMy.tpl');
})
```

When I try to build project with **ionic build android --device** command, all works fine. But when I try to use **--prod** flag, it's occurs a error:

**ionic build android --prod --device**

**Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function `getTemplate`, function calls are not supported.**

How to disable this error or skip it?

P.S. I need function use because I get many templates from remote server, and it's optimize my time for render.
I use Ionic 2 v3 and Angulat 2 v4

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is what the error reads: "*function calls are not supported*".

Using AOT compiler the templates are compiled on build. I don't think dynamic templates could be supported in that kind of build, but I could be wrong here.

Comment: Do you know how to disable AOT Compiler?

Comment: `ng build --no-aot --prod` although that is generally discouraged as a production build for several reasons: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html#!#why-aot